# How can I trim the fat from this SQLite operation?

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, linq-to-sql

I tried to cut out the middle man by using SELECT DISTINCT ... and returning a List, but I couldn't get that to work, so I ended up getting all the vals and then putting them in a HashSet, which will ignore/not accept duplicate values:

```
public async Task<HashSet<String>> SelectDistinctGroupNames()
{
    var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(SQLitePath);
    var allLocations = await db.QueryAsync<SOs_Locations>("SELECT * FROM SOs_Locations");
    HashSet<string> hashsetGroupNames = null;
    foreach (var item in allLocations)
    {
        hashsetGroupNames.Add(item.GroupName);
    }
    return hashsetGroupNames;
}
```

There must be a better way; does anybody know what, though? Maybe a LINQ way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
public async Task<List<String>> SelectDistinctGroupNames()
{
    var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(SQLitePath);
    var groupNames = await db.QueryAsync<string>("SELECT DISTINCT GroupName FROM SOs_Locations");
    return groupNames.ToList();
}
```

This will perform the Distinct operation at the database end, which is far more efficient than fetching all the data from the database and processing it at the client.

Comment: I'll monkey around with this to try to get it to work, but with the code as-is, I get, "Error 1 'string' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection.QueryAsync<T>(string, params object[])'"

-and:

"Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string>'"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Distinct():

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<String>> SelectDistinctGroupNames()
{
    var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(SQLitePath);
    var allLocations = await db.QueryAsync<SOs_Locations>("SELECT * FROM SOs_Locations");
    return allLocations.Select(x=>x.GroupName).Distinct();
}
```

Comment: That's still fetching all the records from the database.

Comment: My impression from your question was that you could not get the SQL for selecting distinct to work, so you abandoned it to instead distinct-ify in code, and wanted terser code for that. Your only problem is getting it into a List?  why did you switch to a HashSet then?

Comment: HashSet automatically ignores/disallows duplicates; IOW, it gives you a distinct set.